# Do the Egyptian gods bleed?

Tags: egyptian

In the 2016 film [Gods of Egypt](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/gods_of_egypt/) the gods bleed a bright golden liquid when hurt (which happens often).

I wonder if there's any basis for this in Egyptian mythology, an Egyptian equivalent to the Greek [ichor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ichor).

Comment: Great question re: ichor!

Comment: @Gibet Why aren't you posting that as an answer???

Answer (score 6):

As far as if they do bleed, yes they do:

> In a passage of the Book of the Dead, Ra cuts himself, and his blood transforms into two intellectual personifications: Hu, or authority, and Sia, or mind.
>   -[Ra, As creator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ra#As_creator)

It is highly unlikely that they bled an ichor equivalent otherwise we would've most likely read about it. But as far as bleeding a liquid, in this case blood, yes they do, or at least Ra does.

Answer (score 2):

In the book *[Tales of Ancient Egypt](https://books.google.com/books?id=gyScOqkJvfUC&printsec=frontcover&dq=tales%20of%20ancient%20egypt&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiFqey8-sPdAhXJ0FMKHWXJA20Q6AEILzAB#v=onepage&q&f=false)* by [Roger Lancelyn Green](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roger_Lancelyn_Green) in the tale called "Horus the Avenger", Set transforms into a hippopotamus:

> And there on the island stood Set himself in the form of a gigantic
>   red hippopotamus.

The song of praise which was sung to recall Set's defeat says:

> Eat the flesh of the vanquished, drink the blood of the red
>   hippopotamus, burn his bones with fire!

Thus, Set, one of the Egyptian gods, apparently did bleed. However, one could argue that this was only because he was in the form of an animal at the time. Indeed, in the entire rest of the book no other gods bleed.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume yes, they bleed.
Especially if you consider that Pharaohs were considered to be not only representatives but hosts and therefore gods themselves.
Pharaohs were often associated with Horus.